# Sampling rate in dacs

Tags: analog, dac, sampling

I am using a DAC form analogous devices viz - AD565A. Now, according to Nyquist theorem the minimal sampling rate for a decent reconstruction of a signal twice the rate of its highest frequency component. Now, the Max sampling rate of different DACs are given in rates ranging from ksps to Gsps. I an not seeing any such sampling rate info on this data sheet. Also, DACs are given a clock input. The sampling rate (Max) is a factor of this clock. Henceforth, if the DAC is given a clock of 10MHz, the max sampling rate (decent) is 10Msps, right ?

Comment: The device is marked as obsolete and no longer available in the datasheet - are you sure you want to use it?

Comment: Its an academic exercise.

Comment: DAC's convert digital values to analogue, they don't 'sample' the data - that would be an ADC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going back to a 1994 databook I have data for the AD565A.

There is no sampling rate specified for this part because it has no clock inputs.

It is a raw DAC with no digital support logic whatsoever. Each digital input directly connects to a switch between Vref and Ground. You can change the input pins at any rate you like!

What IS specified for it is settling time :

- from 10% to 90% in 30ns (meaning you can get high speed outputs with VERY limited accuracy) and
- to 1/2LSB (i.e. full accuracy) within 250 ns.

The latter is the more useful specification. It imposes a useful upper speed limit of 4 MHz sampling rate. But note, to be useful at this speed, you will need an external sample and hold, otherwise you'll see a lot of switching artefacts on your output while the output settles to the new value.

And you need to add the sample time of the S+H to the DAC's own settling time, and this further reduces the useful sampling rate, e.g. with 50ns sample time + 250ns settling time, minimum period is 300ns or sampling rate is 3.3 MHz. (A further note : designing a fast accurate S+H is quite an exercise in itself.)